# Question about Real and Complex places

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading Jurgen Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, p.183

[image]

[image]

Now I'am trying to understand the underlined statement.

Let $v:= \lvert \rvert _{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ be the usual absolute value, so that $\mathbb{Q}_{v} \cong \mathbb{R}$. And let $\bar{v}$ be the unique extension of $v$ to $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_{v} \cong \mathbb{C}$

Let $w \in \mathfrak{p}$. Then by the above (8.1) Extension Theorem (i), there exists $\mathbb{Q}$-embedding $\tau : K \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $ w = \bar{v} \circ \tau$. (Note that since $w|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is also archimedean, it is equivalent to $v$. So we can apply the theorem (8.1)).

Then, we have two cases

Case 1) $im(\tau) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Case 2) $im(\tau) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R}$ ; in this case, by the above (8.1) Extension Theorem  (ii), $\bar{v} \circ \tau = \bar{v} \circ \tau'$ , where $\tau' := \sigma_{2} \circ \tau $
($\sigma_{2} \in G(\mathbb{C} | \mathbb{R})$ is the complex conjugate $\mathbb{R}$-automorphism).

Then,

$ Case 1) \Leftrightarrow K_{w} \cong \mathbb{R}$  ?

$ Case 2) \Leftrightarrow K_{w} \cong \mathbb{C}$ ?

If so, why these are true?

Further progress : By the Ostrowski Theorem, $K_{w} \cong \mathbb{R}$ or $K_{w} \cong \mathbb{C}$. So it suffices to show that "$ Case 1) \Leftrightarrow K_{w} \cong \mathbb{R}$" **or** "$ Case 2) \Leftrightarrow K_{w} \cong \mathbb{C}$".

Is the one of the statements true?

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that "completion" is the same as "closure" (because we are in a complete metric space, namely $\Bbb C$), so:

1. If $\operatorname{im}(\tau) \subset \Bbb R$ then $\overline{\operatorname{im}(\tau)} \subseteq \Bbb R$, but $\Bbb Q$ is already dense in $\Bbb R$, so $\overline{\operatorname{im}(\tau)} = \Bbb R$.
2. Otherwise, take any non-real complex $z \in \operatorname{im}(\tau)$, then $\Bbb Q + \Bbb Q \tau$ is dense in $\Bbb C$, so $\overline{\operatorname{im}(\tau)} = \Bbb C$.